# TypeError: 'Member' object is not callable

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

My code:

```py
global Vc
global Tune
try:
    Vc = await stage.connect()
    Member = guild.me(config["bot_id"])
    await member.edit(suppress=False)
except CommandInvokeError:
    pass
while True:
    while Vc.is_playing():
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
    else:
        Tune = get_info.write_song()
        Vc.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(f"songs/{Tune}"))
        audiofile = eyed3.load(f"songs/{Tune}")
        title = audiofile.tag.title
        await bot.change_presence(activity=discord.Game(name=f"{title}"))
        Vc.source = discord.PCMVolumeTransformer(Vc.source, volume=config["volume"])
        if "suppress=False" in str(stage.voice_states):
            pass
        else:
            await member.edit(suppress=False)
(suppress=False)
```

Error:

```
Member = guild.me(config["bot_id"]) TypeError: 'Member' object is not callable
```

I'm confused about this error...

Comment: It seems like you expect `guild.me` to be a callable function or an instantiable class _(is that a word?)_, but it is not.

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: You're attempting to call `guild.me()`, which means you expect it to be a function or a class object.  But it is not those things, so you cannot use it that way.  An equivalent error would be to assign `x = 1` and then try to call `x()`.  You can't do that, because integer objects cannot be called.  Neither can `Member` objects, which the error message tells you.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure on what your trying to do but it looks like you're trying to get the contents of a member. Am I correct?

Comment: `guild.me` isn't a function. It's an object of the bot

Answer (score 2):

You are mixing up `guild.me` with `guild.get_member()`.

I'm gonna assume you have your bot's ID (or all users) in a database or configuration file that is read into `config`. To retrieve a `Member` object, you could do it as you were doing it in your code, passing the ID, but using the `guild.get_member()` function:

```py
Member = guild.get_member(config["bot_id"])
```

But when the `Member` object you want to retrieve is from your own bot, it is as simple as calling `guild.me`, which will return you a `Member` instance for yourself. See below:

```py
Member = guild.me
```

Documentation:

- [guild.me](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=me#discord.Guild.me)
- [guild.get_member()](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=get_member#discord.Guild.get_member)